# Long Division of Numbers

Tags: math-mode

Following code give the best result if we want to divide numbers.

Question: Suppose I want to make divison of numbers like below image. In that connection is the given code useful or not?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\include{longdiv}

\longdiv{100}{3}

\end{document}
```

We need something like, below image[image]

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284782/typesetting-the-long-division-in-latex help?

Answer (score 2):

May be `xlop` package could be useful for you:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color,xlop}
\begin{document}
\opdiv[style=text]{1}{3} \par 
\opdiv[style=text,maxdivstep=4]{1}{3} \par   
\opdiv[style=text, period]{1}{3} \par 
\vskip3em
\opdiv[maxdivstep=3, displayintermediary=all]{1}{3}
\end{document}
```